# Sum values average between patterns

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a huge text file, each line contains value or text pattern.

How can I find average or at least sum values between each pattern?

Are there any awk/sed or maybe perl solutions?

### Example:

```
pattern1
200
300
pattern2
200
100
200
pattern3
pattern4
```

Expected output:

```
pattern1
250
pattern2
166
pattern3
pattern4
```

Comment: awk and perl would be good languages to use to solve this. Not sed, as it doesn't have any facility for arithmetic. What attempts have you made to solve this, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Will you have values *after* the last pattern?

Comment: No values after last pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
awk '/pattern/{ if (cnt) { printf "%d\n", sum/cnt; sum=cnt=0 } print }
     /^[0-9]+$/{ sum += $1; cnt++ }' file
```

The output:

```
pattern1
250
pattern2
166
pattern3
pattern4
```

Comment: If there are numbers after the last pattern, you'll need to do something in an END block.

Comment: @glennjackman, they won't show up anyway, will be ignored in that case

Comment: Many thanks to @RomanPerekhrest , it works!
I just only add  /pattern1|pattern2/... because have several quite different patterns

Comment: @干猕猴桃, how those patterns are actually look like?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest like different variations of  this:
**PROCESSING: username** or 

**2019-10-22T00:31:02.579576+00:00 stream stop.**

Comment: If you put a `next` at the end of the first block then you don't need to come up with some other regexp to identify the other input lines.

Comment: @EdMorton, only if there won't be non-numeric lines mixed with numeric ones between the patterns. Currently an explicit integers are captured.

Comment: It might actually make more sense to test for all numeric lines and `next` there given the OP says in a comment `I just only add /pattern1|pattern2/... because have several quite different patterns` to avoid all those different "pattenrs" (ugh!) BUT only the OP will know for sure...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Gnu tools sed n dc we can do this:

```
$ sed -re '
    /^[0-9]+$/,/pattern/!b
    /^[0-9]+$/{H;d;}
    x;y/\n/ /
    s#.*#dc -e "0dsn&[+ln1+snz1<+]s+l+xln/p"#ep
    z;x
' file
```

**Results:**

```
pattern1
250
pattern2
166
pattern3
pattern4
```

Assuming the trailing line cannot be a number. Also assuming no negative nums.

We setup a range in sed to look for lines comprising only digits to pattern. Outside this all are printed as is. 
The numbers are appended in hold nd then on tge the pattern line the average is computed using the s///e command of gnu sed utilizing the dc utility.